# how djoser make jwt in django rest

Tags: vue.js, django-rest-framework

I have a frontend of the part I want to get this in vue.I have a login turned out but after the login this does not work . As in djoser url give data by the user .

```
async created() { 
        const response = await axios.get('       ?????????url backend????????????      ',{
        
          headers:{
            Authorizations:'Bearer '+ localStorage.getItem('token')
          }
        });
        console.log(response)
        
        
        
    },



path('auth/', include('djoser.urls')),
    path('auth/token/', obtain_auth_token, name='token'),
    path('customers/', views.CustomerRetrieveView.as_view()),
    path('customers/update/<int:pk>', views.CustomerUpdateView.as_view()),
    path('customers/all', views.CustomerListView.as_view()),
    path('customers/new', views.CustomerCreateView.as_view()),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem here, jwt for the django rest-framework
[How do I get the Django login api to work after extending the user object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65469864/how-do-i-get-the-django-login-api-to-work-after-extending-the-user-object/65486068#65486068)

you can to this, for django jwt

You can do this

settings.py

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ]
}

INSTALLED_APPS = ['rest_framework','rest_framework.authtoken']
```

urls.py

```
from rest_framework.authtoken import views
urlpatterns += [
    path('api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token)
]
```

python manage.py migrate

curl -X POST -d "username=username&password=password123" http://localhost:8000/api-token-auth/

Comment: Instead of copy and pasting the same answer it would make more sense to flag this question as a duplicate of the other one.

Comment: but I made this question myself, and at that link, I don't know how to duplicate what you mean